# If else update sql query to combine multiple queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have empty column `prod2` in table `finance`
I am trying to fill the `prod2` column by comparing with the existing column `product` in `finance`. I know how to write individual queries but can anyone help me to write a single query which performs all the operations.

```
update FINANCE
set prod2 = 'Vegetable'
where PRODUCT='VEG'

update FINANCE
set prod2 = 'Hot Dog'
where PRODUCT='HOT DOG'

update FINANCE
set prod2 = 'Cookie'
where PRODUCT='COOKIE'

update FINANCE
set prod2 = 'Other'
where PRODUCT= NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CASE statement is your best bet:

```
update FINANCE
set prod2 = CASE 
    WHEN PRODUCT = 'VEG' 
        THEN 'Vegetable'
    WHEN PRODUCT = 'HOT DOG'
        THEN 'Hot Dog'
    WHEN PRODUCT = 'COOKIE'
        THEN 'Cookie'
    WHEN PRODUCT IS NULL
        THEN 'Other'
    -- Optional - just in case there is a value in Product that is not one of these values
    -- ELSE Product
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  [CASE EXPRESSION](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/SELECT:_Case_Expression)

```
UPDATE FINANCE
SET prod2 = CASE 
    WHEN PRODUCT='VEG'      THEN 'Vegetable'
    WHEN PRODUCT='HOT DOG'  THEN 'Hot Dog'
    WHEN PRODUCT='COOKIE'   THEN 'Cookie'
    WHEN PRODUCT IS NULL    THEN 'Other'
    ELSE prod2
END;
```